# Activity's instance state: what is automatically stored and restored

Tags: android, android-activity

I have read [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) that the Bundle instance state stores automatically information about each View object in the activity layout.

What other elements are automatically saved and how is that related to the used layout? Could someone explain that process?

Note: I have seen that an manually added fragment to a FrameLayout (fragment is not a view) will be automatically restored (without me adding it again!).